# How to detect a button press in Swift through currentTitle

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, boolean

I am trying to detect a button press while the current title is "Cancel". The button's original title is "Find", but once it's pressed it changes to "Cancel", and I want to do something when the button is pressed when the title is "Cancel".

Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func findMachinesTapped(sender: AnyObject?) {
      //Something is done
      if error = nil{
         self.findButton.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //if self.vizoPoolButton.currentTitle == "Cancel Vizo"{
        //self.deleteRequest()
        //self.loadingNotification.hide(true)
        //}
       }else{
         self.displayAlert("Could not find anything", message: "Try again later")
      }
    }
```

The commented block of code automatically calls the function deleteRequest as soon as the button title changes to "Cancel", and not when it's pressed, while the title is "Cancel".

Comment: Checking the title is a bad idea. It becomes a problem when you support multiple languages.

Comment: I'm using one language though.

Comment: Maybe now. There are better ways to track state. The current label isn't the proper way.

Comment: @Dups rmaddy is correct and answered with tracking state check the code.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated the question and hopefully made it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to check the state of the button when its `selected` state add the code you want else its `default` condition.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected  
    if sender.selected {
    // TITLE IS CANCEL 
    } else {
    // TITLE IS FIND
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an IBAction method for the button. Inside the method check of its title and perform any function.

  ```
  @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
      if let text = sender.titleLabel?.text {
         if text == "Cancel" {
           // Do something
        }
     }    
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Now, this automatically acts as if I pressed the button because it just reads the title, and as mentioned in the question, the button label changes to "Cancel" as soon as it's pressed.

Comment: If it is correct, kindly accept the answer so that it will be useful for others too.

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: So, is it working opposite. Like the button is pressed and its title changes to "Cancel", and inside the function the title remains "Find" right?

Comment: I'm confused. With your function, my code in "// Do something" is automatically read as the function calls the code once the title is "Cancel", and the title changes to "Cancel" when the button is pressed as "Find". What I'm trying to do is read code when the button is pressed as "Cancel", not as soon as the titleLabel is "Cancel"

Answer (score -1):

Make two buttons, one on top of the other.  Set the Cancel button to be disabled while the Find button is enabled.  Once the find button is pressed, do whatever the find button needs to do and then disable the find button and enable the cancel button.